# how to setup a Cambridge Silicon Radio, Ltd Bluetooth Dongle (HCI mode)

Tags: networking, drivers, usb, bluetooth, hardware

Bluetooth setup [docs](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BluetoothSetup) seem a bit dated; my device, but with a different chipset, is on the hardware support [docs](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/HardwareSupportComponentsBluetoothUsbAdapters), however.

```
thufir@mordor:~$ 
thufir@mordor:~$ hciconfig 
hci0:   Type: BR/EDR  Bus: USB
    BD Address: 00:11:22:98:76:54  ACL MTU: 1021:4  SCO MTU: 180:1
    UP RUNNING PSCAN ISCAN 
    RX bytes:1118 acl:0 sco:0 events:39 errors:0
    TX bytes:413 acl:0 sco:0 commands:37 errors:0

thufir@mordor:~$ 
thufir@mordor:~$ hciconfig -a hci0
hci0:   Type: BR/EDR  Bus: USB
    BD Address: 00:11:22:98:76:54  ACL MTU: 1021:4  SCO MTU: 180:1
    UP RUNNING PSCAN ISCAN 
    RX bytes:1118 acl:0 sco:0 events:39 errors:0
    TX bytes:413 acl:0 sco:0 commands:37 errors:0
    Features: 0xff 0x3e 0x09 0x76 0x80 0x01 0x00 0x80
    Packet type: DM1 DM3 DM5 DH1 DH3 DH5 HV1 HV2 HV3 
    Link policy: RSWITCH HOLD SNIFF 
    Link mode: SLAVE ACCEPT 
    Name: 'mordor'
    Class: 0x0c0104
    Service Classes: Rendering, Capturing
    Device Class: Computer, Desktop workstation
    HCI Version: 2.0 (0x3)  Revision: 0x50
    LMP Version: 2.0 (0x3)  Subversion: 0x3
    Manufacturer: Mitel Semiconductor (16)

thufir@mordor:~$ 
thufir@mordor:~$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0a48:3302 I/O Interconnect 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 007 Device 003: ID 0a12:0001 Cambridge Silicon Radio, Ltd Bluetooth Dongle (HCI mode)
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 002: ID 147a:e034 Formosa Industrial Computing, Inc. 
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 003: ID 045e:00cb Microsoft Corp. Basic Optical Mouse v2.0
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 045e:00b4 Microsoft Corp. Digital Media Keyboard 1.0A
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
thufir@mordor:~$
```

also:

```
thufir@mordor:~$ 
thufir@mordor:~$ dmesg | grep Bluetooth 
[ 8112.206222] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.20
[ 8112.206258] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[ 8112.206264] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[ 8112.206267] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[ 8112.206276] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[ 8114.340022] Bluetooth: hci0 command 0x0c12 tx timeout
[ 8132.558756] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[ 8132.558761] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[ 8132.558769] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[ 8146.465549] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[ 8146.465560] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[ 8146.465570] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
thufir@mordor:~$
```

Running 15.10 wily.

How do I enable ______ so that I can access BT through the settings interface?  The `bluez` package is installed.

I've tried a few bluetooth devices, it can't connect with any of them:

[image]

killing and restarting the applet:

```
thufir@mordor:~$ 
thufir@mordor:~$ killall blueman-applet
thufir@mordor:~$ 
thufir@mordor:~$ blueman-applet
blueman-applet version 2.0 starting
Stale PID, overwriting
_________
Load (/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/blueman/main/PluginManager.py:60)
['StatusIcon', 'ExitItem', 'SerialManager', 'AppIndicator', 'Headset', 'PowerManager', 'NetUsage', 'NMPANSupport', 'GameControllerWakelock', 'RecentConns', 'StandardItems', 'TransferService', 'DBusService', 'Menu', 'ShowConnected', 'Networking', 'PPPSupport', 'AuthAgent', 'DhcpClient', 'DiscvManager', 'NMDUNSupport', 'KillSwitch'] 
_________
get_interface_version (/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/blueman/bluez/BlueZInterface.py:13)
Detected BlueZ 5 
_________
__load_plugin (/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/blueman/main/PluginManager.py:133)
loading <class 'blueman.plugins.applet.Headset.Headset'> 
_________
__load_plugin (/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/blueman/main/PluginManager.py:133)
loading <class 'blueman.plugins.applet.Networking.Networking'> 
_________
load_nap_settings (/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/blueman/plugins/applet/Networking.py:36)
Loading NAP settings 
_________
__load_plugin (/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/blueman/main/PluginManager.py:133)
loading <class 'blueman.plugins.applet.StatusIcon.StatusIcon'> 
_________
__load_plugin (/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/blueman/main/PluginManager.py:133)
loading <class 'blueman.plugins.applet.DBusService.DBusService'> 
_________
__load_plugin (/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/blueman/main/PluginManager.py:133)
loading <class 'blueman.plugins.applet.NMDUNSupport.NMDUNSupport'> 
_________
__load_plugin (/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/blueman/main/PluginManager.py:133)
loading <class 'blueman.plugins.applet.Menu.Menu'> 
_________
__load_plugin (/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/blueman/main/PluginManager.py:133)
loading <class 'blueman.plugins.applet.ShowConnected.ShowConnected'> 
_________
__load_plugin (/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/blueman/main/PluginManager.py:133)
Not loading PPPSupport because it's conflict has higher priority 
_________
__load_plugin (/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/blueman/main/PluginManager.py:133)
loading <class 'blueman.plugins.applet.PowerManager.PowerManager'> 
_________
__load_plugin (/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/blueman/main/PluginManager.py:133)
loading <class 'blueman.plugins.applet.KillSwitch.KillSwitch'> 
_________
__load_plugin (/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/blueman/main/PluginManager.py:133)
loading <class 'blueman.plugins.applet.AuthAgent.AuthAgent'> 
_________
__load_plugin (/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/blueman/main/PluginManager.py:133)
loading <class 'blueman.plugins.applet.ExitItem.ExitItem'> 
_________
__load_plugin (/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/blueman/main/PluginManager.py:133)
loading <class 'blueman.plugins.applet.DhcpClient.DhcpClient'> 
_________
__load_plugin (/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/blueman/main/PluginManager.py:133)
loading <class 'blueman.plugins.applet.SerialManager.SerialManager'> 
_________
__load_plugin (/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/blueman/main/PluginManager.py:133)
loading <class 'blueman.plugins.applet.AppIndicator.AppIndicator'> 
_________
__load_plugin (/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/blueman/main/PluginManager.py:133)
Not loading NMPANSupport because it's conflict has higher priority 
_________
__load_plugin (/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/blueman/main/PluginManager.py:133)
loading <class 'blueman.plugins.applet.GameControllerWakelock.GameControllerWakelock'> 
_________
__load_plugin (/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/blueman/main/PluginManager.py:133)
loading <class 'blueman.plugins.applet.TransferService.TransferService'> 
_________
get_interface_version (/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/blueman/bluez/obex/Base.py:20)
Detected BlueZ integrated obexd 
_________
__load_plugin (/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/blueman/main/PluginManager.py:133)
loading <class 'blueman.plugins.applet.DiscvManager.DiscvManager'> 
_________
update_menuitems (/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/blueman/plugins/applet/DiscvManager.py:123)
warning: Adapter is None 
_________
__load_plugin (/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/blueman/main/PluginManager.py:133)
loading <class 'blueman.plugins.applet.RecentConns.RecentConns'> 
_________
__load_plugin (/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/blueman/main/PluginManager.py:133)
loading <class 'blueman.plugins.applet.StandardItems.StandardItems'> 
_________
io_event (/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/blueman/plugins/applet/KillSwitch.py:72)
killswitch registered 0 
_________
io_event (/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/blueman/plugins/applet/KillSwitch.py:72)
State: True 
_________
UpdatePowerState (/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/blueman/plugins/applet/PowerManager.py:159)
off False 
foff False 
on True 
current state True 
new state True 
_________
_on_obex_owner_changed (/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/blueman/plugins/applet/TransferService.py:170)
obex owner changed: :1.59 
_________
on_dbus_name_owner_change (/usr/bin/blueman-applet:94)
org.bluez owner changed to :1.8 
_________
set_nap (/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/blueman/plugins/applet/Networking.py:65)
set nap False 
_________
update_menuitems (/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/blueman/plugins/applet/DiscvManager.py:123)
warning: Adapter is None 
_________
initialize (/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/blueman/plugins/applet/RecentConns.py:144)
rebuilding menu 
_________
enumerate_connections (/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/blueman/plugins/applet/ShowConnected.py:50)
Found 0 existing connections 
_________
on_registered (/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/blueman/bluez/obex/AgentManager.py:18)
/org/blueman/obex_agent 
_________
RequestPowerState (/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/blueman/plugins/applet/PowerManager.py:131)
Requesting True 
_________
on_power_state_change_requested (/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/blueman/plugins/applet/KillSwitch.py:119)
True 
_________
UpdatePowerState (/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/blueman/plugins/applet/PowerManager.py:159)
off True 
foff False 
on True 
current state True 
new state False 
_________
UpdatePowerState (/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/blueman/plugins/applet/PowerManager.py:159)
Signalling False 
_________
check (/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/blueman/plugins/applet/PowerManager.py:119)
callbacks done 
_________
set_adapter_state (/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/blueman/plugins/applet/PowerManager.py:90)
True
```

Comment: Your problem possibly this bug related https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=60824

Answer (score 0):

I also have this device - the Cambridge Silicon Radio Bluetooth Dongle. I am running 16.04 so things might be different. First, the user interface. The command line is `bluetoothctl` part of the bluez package. If you run this command the `list` command should show you the device.

Then the graphical interface, you should be able to find the Bluetooth item in the Settings panel. This is all distinct from the blueman package.

Comment: `bluetoothctl list` lists the bluetooth adaptors. It doesn't solve the problem no adaptors found